Unable to exporting metadata object from Next.js layout.js file
I am trying to add the metadata object in my layout.js file. Hovever, I get the error "You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed.", this seems weird because there is no "use client" in the file. I use  Next.js(14.2.3) App router. I have checked the documentation but i have not been able to find a solution. I also delete the cache files, but still did not work.


Here is the content in my layout.js file
import { Open_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import "./globals.css";
import Navigation from "../components/navigation/Navigation";
import Footer from "../components/footer/Footer";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CookieControlComponent from "../components/cookie/CookieConsent";
import { theme } from "./style";

import { getFooter, getNavigation } from "./lib/pagesApi";

import { GoogleTagManager } from "@next/third-parties/google";
import NextTopLoader from "nextjs-toploader";

import TanstackProvider from "./providers/TanstackProvider";
import ApolloProvider from "./apollo/Apollo";
import TrackingCode from "../components/trackingCode/TrackingCode";

export const openSans = Open_Sans({
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "700"],
  style: ["normal", "italic"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-openSans",
  display: "swap",
});

export const museo = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./fonts/Museo 100.otf",
      weight: "100",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Museo 300.otf",
      weight: "300",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Museo 500.otf",
      weight: "500",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Museo 700.otf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Museo 900.otf",
      weight: "900",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
});

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params: { lang } }) {
  let data = await getNavigation(lang);
  let footerData = await getFooter(lang);

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-NZ6BSN" />

      <body className={museo.className}>
        <noscript>
          <iframe
            src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NZ6BSN"
            height="0"
            width="0"
            style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden" }}
          ></iframe>
        </noscript>

        <TrackingCode />
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <ApolloProvider>
            <TanstackProvider>
              <Navigation data={data?.pages?.nodes[0]} lang={lang} />
              <NextTopLoader />
              <main>{children}</main>

              <Footer data={footerData?.pages?.nodes[0]} lang={lang} />
            </TanstackProvider>
          </ApolloProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
        <CookieControlComponent lang={lang} />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


Can you please share the code of the other files and attach a screen shoot of the file structure of you directory

i have added it
